# JavaScript form validation, check if string contains

Tags: javascript, forms

I have some form validation on my website.

If the account code field contains "XXX" and the reference field is blank, I want an alert to come up for the user to populate the reference field.

I have read that indexOf is the function I need, but the code below does not appear to work. Any ideas?

```
<SCRIPT>
if (form.account.value.indexOf("XXX") != -1 & form.reference.value == "") { 
   alert("Please Enter Reference Number"); 
   form.reference.focus( ); 
   return false; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think you meant [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
if (form.account.value.indexOf("XXX") != -1 && form.reference.value == "") { 
   alert("Please Enter Reference Number"); 
   form.reference.focus( ); 
   return false; 
}
```

This corrects the AND clause, which uses `&&` not `&`.